# Flutter Expanded widget content won't scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

When my `Expanded` widget has expanded there are 20 items, which cause a vertical overflow issue. How do I get the contents within `Expanded` widget to scroll? I've tried wrapping the content in a `SinglechildScrollView` but it still didn't allow scrolling.

```
Scaffold(
    key: key,
    appBar: customappbar,
    body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
            ExpansionTile(
               title: Text(
                            "${_getcurrentselection(context)}:",  
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),                 
               children: <Widget>[
                for (Map<String, dynamic> submenuitemdata in subMenuItems)
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10.0),
                      child: SubmenuItem(submenuitem: submenuitemdata),
                  ),
                 Expanded(
                    child: WebViewWidget(controller: controllerGlobal),
                 ),
              ],
          ),
        ],
   ),
),
```

Comment: `Expanded` and scrolling are used for opposite reasons. `Expanded` is to use remaining space. If there is scrolling there is no remaining space because you sort of have infinite space. You didn't show us your code so it's hard to give advice, but you maybe would want a SinglechildScrollView  with a Column and in that column **no** Expanded

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the information bove to show the code...

Comment: Additionally I replaced the content with singleChildScrollView using a Listbuilder (with no expanded in the expansion tile) but had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your widgets inside a ListView which should be inside the Expanded.

Comment: In this csae that didn't work (although I expected it to. Probably to due with the other widget below it on the page

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a suitable solution sa the Expanded widget below the ExpansionTile widget kept throwing errors no matter what I tried. Instead I placed both inside a Stack, so that the ExpansionTile expands over the top of any other widgets.

Also, minus 2 was a bit harsh

Comment: somebody got their anger out on you. i voted +1